# Can't get Events to show up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to implement event tracking for Google Analytics on a web page that contains Amazon Associate links. I'm not really a programmer (mostly I know HTML and CSS), but no matter how hard I check my JavaScript, I can't figure out why none of my events are registering in Analytics (actually, one of them registered *just once*, but never worked again).

My Analytics property uses Universal Analytics, and I have (just today) upgraded my code, which is now:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-11051086-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

And here's an example of one of the links I'm trying to create an event for:

```
<a onClick="ga('send','event','Amazon','Titlelink','swbook', 0.02)" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345541936" rel="nofollow noreferrer" style="text-decoration: none" target="_blank"><i>Dawn of the Jedi: Into the Void</i> by Tim Lebbon</a><img src="http://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=yodsdatboolis-20&l=as2&o=1&a=0345541936" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

Things I've tried already:

- Adding/removing spaces within the script call
- Setting the last argument to 0
- Using onMouseDown instead of onClick
- Adding the exact same script call to a much simpler element without all the Amazon.com stuff around it.
- etc., etc., etc.

But still nothing, except for that one mysterious time out of dozens that Analytics registered an event.

Would really appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Are you checking in Real-Time to see if all the events show up? The one (out of dozens) time that you see the event, is that in your standard reports? It usually takes up to 24 hours for events to show up in standard GA reports. There doesn't seem to be anything that looks off to me, and I can copy and paste the same code on a test site and see events every time.

Comment: One issue with your code is that the event value parameter does not take floats - you might try to change it for an integer and see if that helps.

Comment: @nyuen Yes, I was checking in real time. On other sites I've seen event tests usually show up in real time...but I suppose I could try waiting for 24 hours.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I did try that already...but if it really doesn't take them, I guess I should change it anyway. You're sure?

Comment: It's in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#eventValue

Comment: Okay, it seems to be working now. The only thing I changed was making the value parameter an integer, as @EikePierstorff suggested (thanks!). I'm pretty sure I did try that before too though, so (wild guess) maybe there was also some kind of caching problem yesterday related to having recently updated the tracking code or something? Or maybe there was just a user error in my methodology, and there's something else I corrected after the last time I tried the integer.